# Hash key in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "student_table")
public class Stduent {

@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
@DynamoDBHashKey
private int id;
```

I am not understanding what is the use of the below code?

```
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
@DynamoDBHashKey
private int id;
```

Answer (score 1):

### [`@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey.html)

> Annotation for marking a hash key or range key property in a class to auto-generate this key. Only String typed keys can be auto generated, and are given a random UUID. The annotation can be applied to either the getter method or the class field for the auto-generated key property. If the annotation is applied directly to the class field, the corresponding getter and setter must be declared in the same class. This annotation can be applied to both primary and index keys.